# How to create a model helper for Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been using `parameterize` to make friendly urls. Example: `@article.title.parameterize`. The problem is for a title like "I'm here" it results in "i-m-here" where I would want "im-here"

I therefore want to create a method all my models can use like so:

```
parameterize_with_apostrophe_removal (string)
string.to_s.gsub("\'", "").parameterize
end
```

With Rails 4 how do I correctly setup a model helper that my models can share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails ships with concerns for adding this type of behavior to models selectively. If this behavior should only apply to some of your models, this is the approach I would take:

```
# app/models/concerns/title_slugs.rb
module TitleSlugs
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def to_slug
    title.to_s.tr("'", '').parameterize
  end
end

# app/models/article.rb
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  include TitleSlugs
end
```

If this behavior were something you would use across all of your models, and on different fields, I might go ahead and add it to `ApplicationRecord`:

```
# app/models/application_record.rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def to_slug(field_name)
    send(field_name).to_s.tr("'", '').parameterize
  end
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Then when you inherit, you get this behavior:

```
article.to_slug(:title) #=> 'your-slug'
```

Comment: Good answer, but isn't `ApplicationRecord` introduced in Rails 5? (OP mentioned Rails 4.) It doesn't matter for concerns (other than a slight change to your example code), but would you recommend adding it to `ActiveRecord::Base` in lieu of `ApplicationRecord`? Or avoid messing with the core class?

Comment: @Max It works in Rails 4 too, but Rails 5 does generate one automatically. I included the relevant bit (`self.abstract_class = true`) here for reference so OP can easily create one in his Rails 4 app. 

As for adding stuff to `ActiveRecord::Base`, it's already a kitchen sink. I wouldn't hesitate to mixin another module if it were the nearest common ancestor. In Rails 4+, however, it's not the best option.

Comment: FYI, this doesn't seem to work in rake tasks. Even if I include the concern in the rake task

Comment: Strange, when I try to load rails console, I get an error `NameError: uninitialized constant Question::TitleSlugs`

Comment: ok I think there was a typo in your answer `title-slugs` not `title_slugs`

Answer (score 0):

I think that's exactly what "concerns" are for in models.  To share methods

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html